# ASP .NET MVC add value to database while view opened

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I am doing a project with ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to post my user's data to my database. But while my view is open, my database added null values. Also, I tried to add `[HttpPost]` attribute. My page gets a 404 Not Found error. Lastly, I click to button, it just adds a new value. And I am not in admin area. So, I created this page by myself.

Here is my controller page:

```
//[HttpPost]
public ActionResult register_page(auth auth)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        auth.abonelik_suresi = DateTime.Now;
        user_manager.Add(auth); // managerdan itemi ekliyoruz.
    
        /* return RedirectToAction("Index");*/ // işlem bittiğinde gönderilecek olan sayfa.
    }
    
    return View(auth);
}
```

AuthManager:

```
public class authManager : Repository<auth>
{
    DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();

    public List<auth> GetAll() //veritabanındaki tüm markaları döndüren metot
    {
        return context.kullanicilar.ToList();
    }

    public auth Get(int id) //sadece id si gönderilen markayı geri döndüren metot
    {
        return context.kullanicilar.Find(id);
    }

    public int Add(auth kullanicilar)
    {
        context.kullanicilar.Add(kullanicilar);
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public int Update(auth kullanicilar)
    {
        context.kullanicilar.AddOrUpdate(kullanicilar);
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public int Delete(int id)
    {
        context.kullanicilar.Remove(Get(id));
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
namespace Entities
{
    public  class auth : IEntity
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string user_name { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string e_mail { get; set; }

        public int phone { get; set; }

        public string abonelik_durumu { get; set; }
        public DateTime abonelik_suresi { get; set; }

        public bool situation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And also, this is my view:

```
@model Entities.auth

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>New User Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>users_info</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.e_mail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.e_mail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.e_mail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

      

    

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.situation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.situation)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.situation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<br />

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your inputs don't have any `name=""`?

Comment: Yes. It does not matter. I am a newbie at .net. I will change how to post their value.

Comment: Please post the complete example, the definition of `auth` and how you intend to post the values as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I edited my question. You can check it. I want to post with input elements. ( You can see the view page)

Comment: Also, There is one more important thing. When I open the view in the browser.  My project always adds null values to my database. I do not want to add it.

Comment: Your model will contain default values if the expected field names weren't in the posted form. But I stand by my first comment, your form input's don't have names, so how are the values supposed to bind to the model properties? If you have some other way to construct the http post body, then you need to include that in your question. And you should use browser developer tools to check what is actually in the http post body.

Comment: Why my model contain default values ? How can i fix it ? İ just want to add data to my databese when i click to Button. Do not thing my view page. İ will fix it.

Comment: I edited my question for add values to my database. Now. It works. But I have the same problem. When I open my page. Default values add to my database. How can I fix it? And Why I get 404 error message when I use HTTPPOST mark?